# Windows 8.1 audio stream not playing in background

Tags: c#, audio, background, stream, windows-8.1

Im making a Windows 8.1 app which can play a audio stream in the background. But it just wont play the audio stream in the background for example if the app is minimized. When the app is in focus it plays the audio stream fine. I hope there is someone that can help. Thanks.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Radio Limfjord" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" FontSize="100" Margin="360,10,360,0"/>
    <MediaElement Visibility="Visible" Name="mediaplayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="True" RealTimePlayback="True" AudioDeviceType="Multimedia" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1218" Margin="0,366,63,177" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" CurrentStateChanged="mediaplayer_CurrentStateChanged" />
    <Button Name="cmdPlay" Content="Afspil" Margin="566,627,0,41" Click="cmdPlay_Click" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    <Button Name="cmdStop" Content="Stop" Margin="714,626,0,41" Click="cmdStop_Click" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    void InitializeTransportControls()
    {
        // Hook up app to system transport controls.
        systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

        // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
        systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
    }

    void MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (mediaplayer.CurrentState)
        {
            case MediaElementState.Playing:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Paused:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Stopped:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Closed:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender,
SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Button)
        {
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                PlayMedia();
                break;
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                PauseMedia();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    async void PlayMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaplayer.Play();
        });
    }

    async void PauseMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaplayer.Pause();
        });
    }

    private void cmdPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaplayer.Source = new Uri("http://media.wlmm.dk/limfjord", UriKind.Absolute);
        mediaplayer.Play();
    }

    private void cmdStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaplayer.Stop();

    }

    private void mediaplayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am having the same issue. I suspect that the format of the stream is the problem. For instance, streaming from DR's netradio doesn't work, but streaming from other radios such as Radio 24syv works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have declare "Audio - Background task" in your app manifest?

Ludo

more : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/12/31/supporting-background-audio-in-your-windows-8-1-app.aspx

Comment: There is a sample of what you are doing, maybe take a look http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff

Comment: Its C++ code. But i looked at it but im still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you ever found and answer to this but looking at your code it doesn't appear that you ever call the InitializeTransportControls() method.